# jsoup parsing tr,td with class and id for loop

Tags: android, parsing, for-loop, html-parsing, jsoup

I am new to jsoup and tried to parse this html
how can one parse it with  jsoup ?

```
  <tr id="bir" >
    <td class ="number"> dsadds </td >
<td class ="name"> dsdad </td >
<td class ="idea"> dvewe </td ></tr>
  <tr id="bir" >
    <td class ="number"> ewe</td >
<td class ="name"> ewe</td >
<td class =idea> dsasdsds </td ></tr>
  <tr id="bir" >
    <td class ="number"> dsadd dsds </td >
<td class ="name"> dsdcdsd adds </td >
<td class ="idea"> dsad dsdsds </td ></tr>
```

here is my code

```
 Elements kelime = document.select("tr#bir td.number");
    Elements anlam = document.select("tr#bir td.name");
    for(Element sectd:kelime){
         for(Element sectd1:anlam){


               result1 = sectd1.text();
               Custom temp = new Custom("Big" + result,"Small" +result1);

                 fetch.add(temp);


           }result = sectd.text();
    }
```

I am adding data to list as I need to show all  td information for a tr in temp file. it is actually for loop problem i think :% but i didnt get it :/.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can parse elements with the class name X by #getElementsByClass(X);

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(yourURL).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
Elements els = doc.getElementsByClass("number");

for (Element el : els) {
    print(el.text());
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

thank you guys for your attention ı fixed the problem here my codes..

```
 Elements kelime = document.select("tr#bir");
    for(Element sectd:kelime){
        Elements tds = sectd.select("td"); 

               result = tds.get(0).text();
               result1 = tds.get(1).text();
               result2 = tds.get(2).text();


               Custom temp = new Custom("Kelime  :" + result,"En erken Türkçe örnek   :" + result1,"Köken   :"+result2);

                 fetch.add(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could only guess what your problem is.

I found two problems:

- your html example results in emptieness if you don't have

  < table > examplehtmlcode < /table>
- you use result in your quote before it has a value; I moved "String result = sectd.text();" before the inner for loop.

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import org.jsoup.*;
  import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
  import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
  import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
  public class CopyOfparser {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args){


  String filepath =   "C:/Users/RH/Desktop/test/1234.html";

  File input = new File(filepath);


  Document document=null;
  try {
      document = Jsoup.parse(input, "ISO-8859-1");
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

  //here starts your code:

  ```
  Elements kelime = document.select("tr#bir td.number");
  Elements anlam = document.select("tr#bir td.name");
  for(Element sectd:kelime){
       String result = sectd.text();

            for(Element sectd1:anlam){


            String result1 = sectd1.text();
            System.out.println("Big" + result +" Small" +result1);


         }

  }
  ```

I got this output:

```
Bigdsadds Smalldsdad
Bigdsadds Smallewe
Bigdsadds Smalldsdcdsd adds
Bigewe Smalldsdad
Bigewe Smallewe
Bigewe Smalldsdcdsd adds
Bigdsadd dsds Smalldsdad
Bigdsadd dsds Smallewe
Bigdsadd dsds Smalldsdcdsd adds
```

Does this help you?